# How to use background-image in inline styles in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a `.vue` file where I want to use inline styles

```html
<img src="~static/img/info/production/pic4.jpg" class="t22" />
<a href="/page/fresco-art" class="btn t23">First text</a>

<div class="hr t24"></div>
<h2 class="t25">Second text</h2>

<ul class="services">
  <li :style="{ backgroundImage: `url('~static/img/info/production/pic5.jpg')` }" class="sq">
    <div class="n">Third text</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The image using tag `<img>` is displayed correctly, but `background-image` in tag `<li>` is not.

How do I specify the file path correctly?

Comment: Did my answer helped you with your issue ?

Comment: @kissu no it didn't work for me. I used this syntax ```<li :style="{ backgroundImage: `url('/img/info/production/ser1.jpg')`}" class="sq">```

Comment: Please try to use **my** syntax.

Comment: @kissu i tried it's doesn't help for me

Comment: Want me to host it for you ?! I'm not sure why it does not help. Please elaborate on an error or why this is not helping. Totally working on my side...

Comment: @kissu i dont know why it doesnt work. I saw this solution many times before

Comment: Okay, so I guess that you **really** needed a hosted solution for this one. I've just updated my answer, hoping this one can help since you do not provide me any error info.

Comment: Hi again, did my answer helped somehow at the end ?

Comment: @kissu Hi bro. I saw this answer three times before your comment. No it didn't work for me

Comment: I created a codesandbox replicating a totally working example. If your code does not work, please do create one too, that way we will be able to inspect and find what is buggy here. We cannot find a solution if you do not provide an example nor any code/errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDIT: really did not expect to have to host this one but here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-nuxt-background-image-bf0ly?file=/pages/index.vue

Exact structure, same (ESlinted) template, working solution. Cannot help beyond this point.

---

I'm not sure that it is the universal solution, but this one is working on my side

```html
<li :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${require('@/static/japan.jpg')})` }">
```

The `require` seems to be required here, not sure why but it works. More in the docs: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets/#images