# NuxtJs accessing local images in assets folder

Tags: vue.js, local, assets, nuxtjs

I think this is a simple question, though don't get why it fails.
I am trying to fetch a local image in nuxt assets folder.

My guess is that Im doing "~" in a string, and thats the reason, but I can't seem to get the image load.

I have tried with following code to access a local image in my nuxt project:

```
<template>
  <div class="background-image" :style="`background-image: url(${imageSource})`">
  </div>
</template>
```

And this is my scripting:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      defaultCoverImage: '~/assets/images/covers/default-cover.jpeg',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    imageSource() {
      if(this.src.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$/)) {
        return this.src;
      }
      return this.defaultCoverImage;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The image does not show up or load correctly. Please check the folder structure below.
The red line is the root folder.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For somebody else who might have the same issue, this is how I solved it (with inspiration of kissus answer below:

```
data() {
    return {
      defaultCoverImage: require('~/assets/images/covers/default-cover.jpeg'),
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68095775/8816585

Also, this should be enough

```html
<div :style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${require('~/assets/images/covers/default-cover.jpeg')})`}">
</div>
```

Comment: If I do this, I can't make it dynamic, like in the example...

Comment: @simon you can totally make it dynamic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68027964/8816585