# image not found in assets when using @error in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a card component which has a structure for an image like this. One image can't be loaded because of (HTTP Status: 403). So I want to replace it with a default one. So I looked it up and learn that I can use @error.

```html
<div class="card-thumbnail">
    <img
       :src="cardImage"
        alt=""
        @error="$event.target.src = '~/assets/images/error.jpeg'"
     />
</div>
```

However this code gives me error that "error.jpeg" can not be found. My folder structure is correct because without @error and a src like this:

> src="~/assets/images/error.jpeg"

I can actually see my error.jpeg. So what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Try out `@error="$event.target.src = require('~/assets/images/error.jpeg')"`

Comment: You need to use the require syntax like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66365980/8816585 also, why do you do an affectation. Wanted to write $emit("something", "error.jpg")`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yep that works. But why ? I mean it is not dynamic tho. It is a static file in my folder

Comment: @kissu I am not sure I understood the affectation thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nuxt 2**

Based on [this](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets#images) you need to use `require` because images inside assets directory are considered as modules :

```
@error="$event.target.src = require('~/assets/images/error.jpeg')"
```

**Nuxt 3**

if the image is in `public` folder :

```
   @error="$event.target.src = '/images/error.jpeg'"
```

if it's in `assets` folder :

```
  @error="$event.target.src = '~/assets/images/error.jpeg'"
```

Comment: Does not work on Nuxt3 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt3 Solution:

```
<template>
<div class="card-thumbnail">
    <img
       :src="cardImage"
        alt=""
        @error="$event.target.src = image"
     />
</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import image from '~/assets/images/error.jpeg'
</script>
```

Reference: [Why loading dynamically assets fails on Nuxt v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74688433/why-loading-dynamically-assets-fails-on-nuxt-v3)